# With Next.js, should I still use the api folder and handler to call endpoints of an existing backend?

Tags: next.js

I'm discovering Nextjs.

It seems like it can be used as a full stack framework.
From my understanding, using Nextjs this way involved that you gotta you backend in the api folder.

Considering I just wanna hit endpoints of an existing backend, should I still use the api folder to write the axios (or fetch) requests? Or should I make the calls from the components?

What would be the good practice?

Comment: It really depends. If the endpoints are already built it's ok to just call them directly. However, if you for some reason want to hide/mask the service's URL, or don't want to expose certain environment variables to the client, you can call these endpoints from your own Next.js API endpoints.